# How to call R functions from Free Pascal?

Tags: r, freepascal, pca

In my Lazarus/Free Pascal application I generate a large multi-column numerical matrix. I want to run a [Principal Component Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) (PCA) on this table, but cannot seem to find any packages to do so.

The R language has a .dll library that exports the [PCA function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/princomp.html), but it returns an object of the class "princomp." I am not sure how I would then go about extracting relevant information (such as the transformed matrix) from this class for use within Lazarus/FPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at ALGLIB:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGLIB

http://www.alglib.net/download.php

I think it has many numerical routines, among other singular value decomposition and eigenvalue decomposition. So if it does not have a special PCA routine, remember that the PCA mean vector is the mean of all the data vectors and that the PCA vectors are the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix and the corresponding eigenvalues are the variances of the projection of the data on those vectors.

Comment: Great, thank you for the information - that clears up a lot for me. Can you tell me - once I have the PCA vectors, how do I apply the same process to a single query point? Is there a coefficient for each vector could be used to transform it to an eigenvector?

Comment: Assuming you have m n-dimensional data vectors X_i, PCA will give you a nx1 mean vector A and n orthonormal PCA nx1 vectors B_j. A data vector X_i can now be projected on a principal component with index j to obtain a weight w_j by  w_j = (B_j)'*(X_i - A) (where ' is the transpose) The point is to find a compact approximate representation of the data in the form of a few weights obtained this way by projection on the most important principal components. I am not sure whether this answered the question. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two PCA functions in R: princomp and prcomp. The first calculates the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of the data, the second performs a singular value decomposition. The details about what each function returns (an object of class "princomp" or "prcomp") are described in the help pages of the functions under the section "Value". Typically these are a matrix with the loadings (i.e. the rotation matrix), the standard deviations of the principal components (i.e., the square roots of the eigenvalues of the      covariance/correlation matrix), and, if requested, the rotated dataset.